# Version control system locally

Tags: version-control

Is there any software that does the version controlling of a module locally.
Without actually using the internet can we just have a setup of all the versions of software internally.
Please recommend one.

Answer (score 4):

Distributed version control systems such as Mercurial and Git allow you to create local repositories.  These can either be on a local network or just within a single directory tree.

Comment: You should consider having a remote repository at least to make sure your work is backed up.  But it doesn't have to be an online service.  Something as simple as a folder on a network share will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[Git SCM](https://git-scm.com/) is a great choice. You can use it on a single machine like your own PC or laptop. You can also set up a Git server in your Intranet, so you can still have a team working on a software. It's free to use even for commercial use.

There are the [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases), which integrate into Windows Explorer. Depending on the IDE you use, it may even have Git support built in (e.g. Visual Studio or Pycharm).

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) is very popular. I have been using it for decades at work.

I also use it at home, on a single laptop (using XAMPP on Windows to get an Apache server).

The [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) GUI makes it simple to use, although the command line is not difficult to learn.

Subversion is stable, popular and well documented & supported  (more than 116 ***thousand*** questions and answers [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=svn) alone)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility on linux is to use RCS, which is a tool to version individual files locally.  Dead simple to use, minimal amount of extra clutter, no server to set up, and especially appropriate for a lone developer.